# Find the longest, Non-NA common sequence between two time series in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-science

Say I have two, different-length time series. Both have columns `time` and `value`. Both of them have NA values at random positions. For example:

```
# Generate first series
series1 <- data.frame(
    time = seq.POSIXt(
        from = as.POSIXct("2020-01-01", origin = "1970-01-01"),
        length.out = 100,
        by = "1 day"
    ),
    value = runif(100, min = 0, max = 100)
)

# Generate second series, which starts and ends and different times
series2 <- data.frame(
    time = seq.POSIXt(
        from = as.POSIXct("2019-12-01", origin = "1970-01-01"),
        length.out = 80,
        by = "1 day"
    ),
    value = runif(80, min = 0, max = 100)
)

# Remove some values at random
random_idx1 <- sample(seq_len(nrow(series1)), 20)
random_idx2 <- sample(seq_len(nrow(series2)), 20)

series1$value[random_idx1] <- NA
series2$value[random_idx2] <- NA
```

Great. If I were to determine the largest non-NA sequence for each series, I could use `stats::na.contiguous()`. However, the longest sequence for one series is not the same for the other.

Now the question is: how can I determine the longest **overlapping** Non-NA sequence of values between the two series? That is, what is the longest sequence of values that are time-matched between the two time series AND are not NA values?

Comment: Perhaps you want to join them by 'time' `merge(series1, series2, by = 'time', all = TRUE)`

Comment: Right, then one could use na.contiguous on the merged frame?

Comment: I was trying your example, but I don't find cases that are common to both i..e `full_join(series1, series2, by = 'time') %>% summarise(len1 = list(rle(!is.na(value.x) & !is.na(value.y))))`. may be it is because of the example that you construct are not overlapping

Comment: @akrun  I updated the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the question series2 ends in 2019 whereas series1 starts in 2020 so there is no run of non-NA values in common so let us use a different example given in the Note at the end.

**1)** Using only base R we could do this:

```
na.contiguous(merge(DF1, DF2, by = 1))
```

**2)** or we could convert to zoo and do the same thing. Use fortify.zoo(z) to convert back or just leave it as zoo.  If you want separate zoo objects use z$z1 and z$z2. Note that time(z) is the times in the result.  It would also be possible to use ts class if the times are regularly spaced: as.ts(z).

```
library(zoo)
z1 <- read.zoo(DF1)
z2 <- read.zoo(DF2)

z <- na.contiguous(cbind(z1, z2))
z
##   z1 z2
## 3  3 12
## 4  4 13
## 5  5 14
## attr(,"na.action")
## [1] 1 2 6 7
## attr(,"class")
## [1] omit
```

### Note

```
DF1 <- data.frame(1:6, c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, NA))
DF2 <- data.frame(2:7, c(NA, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16))
```

Answer (score 1):

We do a `full_join` by 'time', apply run-length-id (`rle`) on the logical vector i.e. non-NA elements of 'value.x' and 'value.y', extract the `lengths` where the 'values' are TRUE, get the `max`

```
library(dplyr)
full_join(series1, series2, by = 'time') %>% 
     summarise(len1 = with(rle(!is.na(value.x) &
           !is.na(value.y)), max(lengths[values])))
# len1
#1    5
```

It returns the largest non-NA elements common to both 'value' columns from 'series1' and 'series2' dataset